Filter function to reference another sheet's Value If check marked
I have a Google workbook where I'm trying to use the Filter function to add any items from the main sheet(Listings) under column B to the Sold sheet if  column A is check marked under the Listings Sheet. I want to keep the URLs, so I was told filter would be the best function to use.
What would be the correct formula in order to get the values under column B into the Sold sheet if Column A under Listings is check marked?
Listings Sheet
Sold Sheet
Currently, my formula is
=filter(Listings!B2:B100,Listings!A2:A100="True")
But that's giving me an N/A error. I also tried
=filter(Listings!B2:B100,"Select B Where A contains "True")
But that's also giving me the same error.
Expected result is for the value of column B to import into the Sold sheet if that item has a check mark under Column A of the Listings sheet

HI and thank you! I tried =filter(Listings!B2:H100,Listings!A2:A100=true) and that worked!

I posted an answer instead, and edited it to add a suggestion. Please accept it if it worked.

Please don't use images of your data, and instead insert a text table with sample data.

The string "True" is different from the boolean (true or false) value true. So your first formula is correct, just change it to:
=filter(Listings!B2:B100, Listings!A2:A100=true) .
Suggestion
You can also use arrayformula to handle the case where no tickboxes are selected:
=arrayformula(ifna(filter(Listings!B2:B100, Listings!A2:A100=true), "")) .
References

ARRAYFORMULA
IFNA

